# Delphi how to remove Code Completion totally?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, code-completion

My IDE hangs for minutes since I work on a big project every time I press "." or do CTRL+SPACE.

If I am lucky I hit the ESC key on time, if not I must wait 1 minute while banging my head against the table.

I want to totally disable it, how to do?

Comment: How big is this project? I've got one with about a million lines, but hardly ever experience delays. And if I do, it's usually for just a couple of seconds.

Comment: @golez Program is buggy. Sometimes it goes into infinite loop doing insight.

Comment: @David: Out of curiosity, why is the 'infinite loop' terminated after a few minutes?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It doesn't terminate for me. XE3 appears to be better.

Comment: I have found the IDE works better if the code is compiled (successfully) before trying code insight, refactoring, etc...

Answer (score 12):

Andreas Hausladen's IDE Fix Pack does wonders for several performance issues in Delphi IDE

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack-2009-10/

And this is one of them.

Comment: I think you answered how to make code completion faster, not how to disable it, which is what the questions actually asked for.

Comment: @RobKennedy In a literal meaning perhaps, but the actual issue is obviously about the time it took, disabling it being only an expedient.

Comment: I have just now downloaded the Andreas Fix Pack and it made a huge difference! Now it is fast to load, use code insight, etc. Before that was boring using and frustrating many times.

Answer (score 5):

After searching for the 10th times I found it:

Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight

when you really want to find something in a UI it is difficult to find it...

Comment: You can use IDE insight, press `CTRL + .` and enter `Code Insight`.